# Include source files from folder using Google GYP

Tags: node-gyp, gyp

Is there a way I can include all the *.cc files in a project that is in another directory using Google GYP? I have looked [at this page](https://code.google.com/p/gyp/wiki/InputFormatReference#Pattern_Lists_%28/%29) but it has not turned really helpful.